# Can't get custom e-mail client to show up in default application selector

Tags: settings, mimetype

I use a nightly version of Thunderbird. Which means I have to use my own Desktop file if I want it to work properly (and not mess up everything).

It currently looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Thunderbird Daily
GenericName=Mail Client
Comment=Mails, Calendars and Chat
TryExec=thunderbird
Exec=thunderbird --class=Daily %U
Icon=thunderbird
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;Email;
Keywords=GPG;PGP;XMPP;Jabber;Task;Todo;IMAP;POP;SMTP;Newsgroup;E-Mail;Mail;
MimeType=text/plain;text/eml;text/calendar;application/rss+xml;x-scheme-handler/mailto;x-scheme-handler/irc;x-scheme-handler/xmpp;x-scheme-handler/webcal;message/rfc822;x-scheme-handler/news;x-scheme-handler/snews;x-scheme-handler/nntp;x-scheme-handler/feed;
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Daily
Terminal=false
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
X-MultipleArgs=false
```

It used to have a lot more categories and I also tried just specifying `x-scheme-handler/mailto` like pantheon mail does, to no avail.

The desktop file is in my .local/share/applications folder, where I have other desktop files. I can select Thunderbird Daily as my default Calendar application. Or even text editor, should maybe remove that text/plain...

Further, desktop-file-validate has no issues with it.

Yet I can not select Thunderbird Daily as my default mail application, only pantheon mail is available.

I'm on 0.4.1 Loki with the settings app at version  2.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually forcing an update (i.e. editing) `mimeinfo.cache` and `mimeapps.list` in `~/.local/share/applications` solved this.

The proper way to do it would be to execute `update-mime-database`.